# Failed to load joint?_*_controller

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.4.

I have made

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control
```

and I have downloaded the gazebo_ros_demos into my

```
catkin_ws/src
```

I want to try http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control .

Until I type

```
   $ roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch
```

everything is fine.

But then, when I type

```
   $ roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch
```

then it says

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1403516339.376075] [33.377000] Failed to load joint_state_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1403516340.379782] [34.378000] Failed to load joint1_position_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1403516341.383720] [35.379000] Failed to load joint2_position_controller
```

What have I made wrong? What can I do, so that it works?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174551/failed-to-load-joint?_*_controller/) by [fhurlbrink](https://answers.ros.org/users/18571/fhurlbrink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install the `ros-hydro-ros-controllers` package.

I just fixed a broken link in the tutorial's installation instructions:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-request/17/fix-broken-link/diff

If you feel that some part of the installation instructions is not clear enough, please consider contributing an additional documentation patch.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2